# Java Button Problems

Tags: java, jbutton

I have this code in which I am trying to open a class with the click of a button. When I run the program the buttons do nothing. I tested to see if I was referencing something wrong but without the buttons the class opened. Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;    
import javax.swing.*; 

public class mainClass{
    public static void main(String args[]){

        JOptionPane frame = new JOptionPane(JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        Object[] options = {"Easy Mode","Medium Mode","Hard Mode"};

        int n = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame,"Which difficulty do you want to play on?","Higher or Lower Game",JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options,options[2]);

        String STRn = String.valueOf(n);

        if(STRn.equals(options[0])){

            EZMode ezmode = new EZMode();
            ezmode.easyMode();

        }else if(STRn.equals(options[1])){


        }else if(STRn.equals(options[2])){


        }           
    }
```

Comment: what Buttons are you talking about?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION` and `QUESTION_MESSAGE` should switch places. (from [oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html)) - _JOptionPane(Object message, int messageType, int optionType, Icon icon, Object[] options, Object initialValue)_

Comment: The buttons that there will be in the JOptionPane which were defined in the array in my case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`showOptionDialog`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showOptionDialog-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-int-int-javax.swing.Icon-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Object-) returns the indices of the option selected not the value of the string itself. Try this

```
if (n == 0) {
   // do stuff for button 1
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

`String STRn = String.valueOf(n);`

Don't use this

Instead ***use respective values of n*** for conditional if statements' implementation